# How to pass many2one field from Form view to wizard in odoo 10?

Tags: python, odoo-10

I need to pass many2one field drop down option to wizard view to display records based on that passed option.

Comment: Hi, You can use context to do it

Answer (score 0):

In your python file:

```
return {
            'name': _('Wizard Name'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'res_model': 'model.name',
            'view_id': False,
            'views': [view_id],
            'target': 'new',
            'context': {'default_field_name':self.field_name}
        }
```